# How to access $route property inside setup method (Vue 3)?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api, vue-router4

How can I access $route.params property inside setup method in Vue.js? When I try to access it inside other method, or inside template everything works fine, but i cannot access it inside setup method.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use composable function [`useRoute`](https://next.router.vuejs.org/api/#useroute) to get the current route:

```js
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";
    export default {
        setup() {
          const route =useRoute()
          //then use route.params 
           
        },
    };
```

Comment: This worked for me - `const route = useRouter();let id = route.currentRoute.value.query.id;`